# ¿Cómo dibujar grafo de dependencias de asignaturas?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, web, teoría-de-grafos

Como parte de un ejercicio práctico me han solicitado que en el sitio web debo dibujar un grafo de dependencias entre las asignaturas de una carrera.

Por ejemplo: https://www.fing.edu.uy/tecnoinf/sanjose/cursos/previas.pdf

Tengo toda la información acerca de las relaciones, el problema es dibujarlo.

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer algo así?, ¿Existe alguna libreria que me ayude?

Información adicional:

- Estoy usando Angular con Angular Material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la biblioteca [vis-network](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vis-network), a la que básicamente pasas cada *curso* en el conjunto de *nodos* y las dependencias entre cursos en el arreglo de *edges*.

Puedes *decorar* cada *edge* para hacer ver, de manera gráfica, tal como el ejemplo que muestras, el tipo de relación de dependencia que hay entre los cursos.

También puedes manipular la posición y los colores, entre muchas otras opciones.

He preparado un pequeño ejemplo con algunos de los primeros cursos de mi carrera de Ing. en Ciencias y sistemas:

```js
  // nodos
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
      {id: 1, label: 'Matemática 1', x: 0, y: 0}
    , {id: 2, label: 'Matemática 2', x: 150, y: 0}
    , {id: 3, label: 'Matemática 3', x: 300, y: 0}
    , {id: 4, label: 'Matemática 4', x: 450, y: 0}
    , {id: 10, label: 'Física Básica', x: 150, y: 90}
    , {id: 11, label: 'Física 1', x: 300, y: 90}
    , {id: 12, label: 'Física 2', x: 450, y: 90}
    , {id: 21, label: 'Intr. Progra 1', x: 450, y: 180}
    , {id: 22, label: 'Intr. Progra 2', x: 600, y: 180}
    , {id: 23, label: 'Estruct/datos', x: 750, y: 180}
  ]);
 
  // edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
      {from:  1, to:  2, arrows: "to"}
    , {from:  2, to:  3, arrows: "to"}
    , {from:  3, to:  4, arrows: "to"}
    , {from: 10, to: 11, arrows: "to"}
    , {from: 11, to: 12, arrows: "to"}
    , {from: 21, to: 22, arrows: "to"}
    , {from: 22, to: 23, arrows: "to"}
    , {from:  1, to: 10, arrows: "to", dashes: true}
    , {from:  2, to: 11, arrows: "to", dashes: true}
    , {from:  3, to: 12, arrows: "to", dashes: true}
    , {from:  3, to: 21, arrows: "to"}
    , {from:  4, to: 22, arrows: "to", dashes: true}
 ]);
 
  // acá creamos la _red_
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  var options = {physics: {
          enabled: false,
        },};
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```css
    #mynetwork {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Visita la carpeta de [ejemplos](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/tree/master/examples/) dentro del proyecto para hacerte una mejor idea de sus capacidades.

Answer (score 1):

[Vis Network](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vis-network) te permite trabajar con algo similar, es muy sencilla de usar, maneja datasets de arreglos de nodos y arreglos de asociaciones, te dejo los ejemplos para que puedas darles un vistazo y encuentres el diseño que más se apegue:  https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/